# Complex JSON response with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, web-services

I've been teaching myself angularjs slowly via w3schools and other sites and i am trying to download and interpret some json. I have successfully done this with a very basic json url (http://ip.jsontest.com) but in a more complex response i am having trouble deciphering the layers.

Can someone please give me a hand. I've put the code in paste bin because my browser was having a very hard time trying to get it display correctly for you here :/

http://pastebin.com/a2sRxZWc

JSON url im hitting is here

http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60901/IDN60901.95764.json

Cheers

edit: added code based on feedback and help. To answer the other questions, i used copyright url as an example. One of the repeatable ones is 'air_temp'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ names.observations.copyright_url }}
  </li>
</ul>




</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60901/IDN60901.95764.json")
  .success(function(data) {$scope.names = data;});

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the json? Write all of it out? From looking at the json there is only every one copyright url so a repeat doesn't make sense

Comment: Paste the code to the question, highlight it, and click on the "code" button in the toolbar (looks like `{}`)

Comment: I have now pasted the code, thanks for the help with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` tag needs to be corrected.

try following...

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names.observations.notice">
      {{x.copyright_url}}
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names.observations.header">
      {{x.product_name}}
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names.observations.data">
      {{x.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help but this does not appear to have fixed it. Still getting blank. Have checked i am getting a successful json response and i am.

Comment: adjusted answer to consume the given json.